# Template class arguments inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Say I have a base class:

```
class Clickable{
//virtual functions
};
```

How can I go about creating a templated class that will only accept as an argument classes that inherit from Clickable:

```
template < class T : public Clickable > class scrollingList{
    std::vector<T> elements;
    //...
};
```

Is the above possible, and, if not, how could I do what I described in the beginning?

Comment: You can either use 'std::enable_if' for this (SFINAE) or do a 'static_assert'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the base class with a `static_assert`

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of<Clickable, T>::value, "Wrong base type!");
```

That will give you a compile time error if `T` is not derived from `Clickable`.

Answer (score 1):

Bo Persson's answer is the correct one for C++11 and later; but if you are restricted to earlier versions of C++, the following should work:

```
char is_clickable(void*);
char (&is_clickable(Clickable*))[3];

template<typename T> class ScrollingList
{
  typedef int dummy[(int)sizeof(is_clickable((T*)0))-2];
  std::vector<T> elements;
  ...
};
```

The trick here is that overload resolution will choose the first overload if `T` is not derived from `Clickable` and the second one if it is. However the first one will cause declaration of an array of size −1 which is of course not allowed.